# Custom result filter vs InvalidModelStateResponseFactory in ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, action-filter

I can use a custom result filter inherited by `IResultFilter` to return response in case of a model-validation failure:

```
public class FailedValidationResultFilter : IResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.ModelState.IsValid)
            return;

        //other logic to create the ProblemDetails response
    }

    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Or I can use this in `Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services
    .AddControllers();
builder.Services
    .Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(x => x.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = ctx => new ValidationProblemDetailsResult(););
```

`ValidationProblemDetailsResult`:

```
public class ValidationProblemDetailsResult : IActionResult
{
    public async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        //logic here and then followed by this:
        var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
        {
            Type = "",
            Title = "Invalid parameters",
            Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest,
            Detail = "Your request parameters didn't validate.",
            Instance = "",
            //Extensions = 
        };

        var objectResult = new ObjectResult(problemDetails) { StatusCode = problemDetails.Status };
        await objectResult.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
    }
}
```

**Question:** which one should I prefer and why? Also, please provide scenario(s), to better understand their uses/pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

In WeiApi projects,the [ApiController] attribute makes model validation errors automatically trigger an HTTP 400 response.

and your codes

```
builder.Services
    .Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(x => x.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = ctx => new ValidationProblemDetailsResult(););
```

replaced the default BadrequestResult with your custom result,when it trigger 400 resopnse automaticlly(In an other words,it  works only when your controller is attached with [ApiController] attribute and applied to all actions in the controller  ) ,you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#automatic-http-400-responses-1) related

With a filter,you could choose to apply it to certain controller/action or all actions whenever the controller is attached with ApiControoler Attribute or not,the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#filter-scopes-and-order-of-execution) related